# Proving that limit of dot product equals dot product of limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $\lim_{\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{c}} \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{L}$ and $\lim_{\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{c}} \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{K}$. I want to prove that $\lim_{\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{c}} \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})\bullet \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{L}\bullet \mathbf{K}$, where $\bullet$ denotes the Euclidean dot product.

Let $\epsilon >0$. We know that $\exists \delta_1, \delta_2>0$ such that $\forall \mathbf{x} \in A : 0<\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}\|<\delta_1$ implies $\|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{L}\|<\epsilon$ and $0<\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}\|<\delta_2$ implies $\|\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{K}\|<\epsilon$.

Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$. We have $|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})\bullet \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}) -\mathbf{L}\bullet \mathbf{K}|= |\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})\bullet \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}) -\mathbf{K} \bullet \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})+\mathbf{K} \bullet \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{L}\bullet \mathbf{K}|=|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})\bullet (\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{K})+\mathbf{K}\bullet (\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{L})|\leq |\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})\bullet (\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{K})|+|\mathbf{K} \bullet (\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{L})|$.

The Cauchy-Schwartz inequality yields $|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})\bullet \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}) -\mathbf{L}\bullet \mathbf{K}|\leq \|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})\|\|\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{K}\|+\|\mathbf{K}\|\|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{L}\|.$

If we let  $0<\|\mathbf{x} -\mathbf{c}\|<\delta$, I'll
just need an upper bound for $\|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})\|$, but I can't find one. I'd appreciate help finishing the argument.

Comment: Notice that $(f,g)$ is continuous at $(c,d)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Modify your argument slightly by choosing $\delta_1$ so that $0<\|\mathbf x-\mathbf c\|<\delta_1\implies \|\mathbf f(\mathbf x)-\mathbf L\|<\min(\epsilon,1)$. This will tell that you that $\|\mathbf f(\mathbf x)\|<\|\mathbf L\|+1$ when $0<\|\mathbf x-\mathbf c\|<\delta_1$. Can you finish now?

Answer (score 3):

The upper bound you want is $\lVert f(x)\rVert\le \lVert f(x)-L\rVert+\lVert L\rVert$